# Photoshop CS6 - Export Layers to files always exports frames backwards

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, export

I have been having the most frustrating issue when exporting animations as layer files. Here is how it goes:

I create my animation on the timeline and then choose "Flatten frames into layers" from the timeline options. I then delete my original layers and just have the flattened frames as layers.

Now I want to export these layers ad individual PNG files so I go File > Scripts > Export Layers to Files. I name my file, choose settings etc and it exports my files.

The problem I'm having is photoshop exports the last frames first and adds this annoying numbering system so all my files are numbered backwards.

Here are examples of what the file names will look like:

countdown_0000_Frame-42.png, countdown_0001_Frame-41.png
and
countdown_0041_Frame-1.png, countdown_0040_Frame-2.png

[image: screenshot of files as they export]

Now when you try to add the frames into unity for example, you have to add each one individually instead of being able to drag in the whole folder.

If someone can help me with this i will be eternally grateful!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually pretty sure this is because of the Layer Order.
Just select the layers you want to export with this Method and go to Layer -> Arrange -> Reverse.
Then Export them again and everything should be fine :)

EDIT: You also can just change the order in which the Names are listed within the Explorer.
Just right-click -> Sort By and then change from Ascending to Descending.

Answer (score 0):

I used to do the most tedious work in PS that resulted in have to produce hundreds of layers with tiny modifications and had exactly the same issue when exporting.

If your running Windows - 'Bulk Rename Utility' will let you just chop of the first X characters of the selected files in a folder and problem solved.

I did at one point have a JS script for exporting layers which stripped the numbering, but that seems to have gone walk-about.